# The expanded help text for comment flags shows a variable name instead of a value

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, flag-queue

As a new mod, I systematically went through the system and expanded every helpful-looking block of text in sight. When I went to expand the help text for handling comment flags in the queue sidebar, this is what I see:

[image]

`$threshold2` looks an awful lot like it shouldn't be there. Perhaps localization? In any case, it should probably be fixed.

Comment: You're not quite a mod yet. :) *(At least not on Stack Overflow)* :)

Comment: @jmort253 On [softwarerecs.se] he is. ;)

Comment: Ah, well congrats!  I know you're running in the SO elections, so I made the assumption... we all know what they say about assumptions...

Comment: I'm happy to see this bug, since it illustrates that new moderators *can* read the guidance that the rest of us have long ago become blind to!

Comment: That is [tag:status-by-design]. It is your personal `$threshold2` as in *I'm allowed to eat $threshold2 cookies*. I use that all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perhaps localization?

Perhaps. We admit nothing.

Anyways... this is fixed in the next build (rev 2014.2.24.1392, Meta rev 2014.2.24.1979)